# Why is JQuery passing null array to MVC controller, instead of string array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc

Ok, so my question is two pronged. I am trying to retrieve specific string values from selected rows into a JQuery array:

```
<script>
var finalCSG=[]; 
$('.checkbox').change(function () {
        var csg = [];
        var checkedRows = $('.checkbox:checked'); 
        $.each(checkedRows, function (index, item) 
        { 
            var row = $(this).closest('tr');
            csg.push(row.find('.connote').text());
        })
        finalCsg = csg;
    });
</script>
```

My first question: The contents of array 'finalCsg' are supposed to be simple alphanumeric strings, but they contain lots of leading and trailing spaces (when I used console.log to check them out). How do I resolve this?

Now, the second and more pressing issue. I try to pass this array to my MVC controller (with a button click), with the following code:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Assign", "TransactionHistory")';
    document.getElementById("AssignButton").onclick = function () { myFunction() };
    function myFunction() {

        $('#myDiv').load(url, { csgList: finalCsg })
    }
```

'TransactionHistory' is my controller name. Even here, the variable csgList contains the proper array elements (with those spaces I described earlier, though, when I check with console.log). But my controller only gets a null string. The controller is defined like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Assign(List<string> csgList)
    { 
        return Content("Hi");
    }
```

I initially tried using string[] csgList as the parameter, and then tried List but it always gets a null value (or empty string I guess) from JQuery (The return statement is just to test, does not really mean much now). Some posts mention the use of a 'traditional' keyword, but I am not primarily a front end developer (I am covering for someone at work, with strict deadlines) so I couldn't use that to proper effect.

Any inputs would be greatly beneficial.

Comment: Your parameter is an collection, so the data needs to be `{ [0].csgList: someValue, [1].csgList: anotherValue, .... }` (i,e. indexed) or you need to stringify the data and set `contentType: 'json'` (or you can use `traditional: true` option. Its easier to do this using `$.ajax()`.

Comment: Either `string[]` or `IEnumerable<string>` or List<string>` are all fine. But you cannot pass `csgList` as it is. It needs to be as I noted in the first comment - e.g. stringified using `JSON.stringify()` and set the `contentType` option

Comment: But if I need to change JQuery code, where exactly do I make the changes you specified (like stringifying the data, using$.ajax(), setting traditional: true etc.)?

Comment: Ok, thanks a ton! I'll be waiting for that. The answer could save my job...for now, untl I seek a different one which matches my skillset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you passing an array of simple values, then you can use the `traditional: true` ajax option to correctly bind to your `List<string> csgList`.

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Assign", "TransactionHistory")';
var element = $('#myDiv');
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    traditional: true,
    data: { csgList: finalCsg },
    success: function (response) {
        element.html(response);
    }
});
```

An alternative is to `stringify` the data and set the `contentType` option (and this alternative is required if your array contains objects rather than simple values)

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({ csgList: finalCsg }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (response) {
        element.html(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please let me know how your code can be triggered when I click the button with the id 'AssignButton'? Do I need to put your code after 
document.getElementById("AssignButton").onclick =
or can I replace it with $('#AssignmentButton').Click()?

Comment: `$('#AssignButton').click(function(){ ...ajax call ... })`